# While exporting new object via require.js: does it actually create "new" object or just returns an instance of existing

Tags: javascript, module, singleton, requirejs

Let's assume I have modules A, B and C in require.js. Module A export new object.

```
define(function() {

    // constructor
    function F() {
        this.prop = 'some';
    }

    // module exports
    return new F();   

});
```

Modules B and C imports instance of F() from A:

```
define(['A'], function(f_inst) {
    // code
});
```

For some reason I need F to be singleton. I have not serious understanding of how require.js works. So, this is my question: do I need to use singleton patterns for F() in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AMD module `define`d, only once. Even if you require it multiple times, it will be evaluated only once.

You may checkout this example:

**F.js**

```
define(function() {

    // constructor
    function F() {
        this.prop = 'some';
    }

    // module exports
    console.log('evaluated!');
    return new F();   

});
```

---

**A.js**

```
define(['./F'], function(F) {
    return 'A';
});
```

---

**B.js**

```
define(['./F'], function(F) {
    return 'B';
});
```

---

**main.js**

```
require(['./A', './B'], function(A, B) {
    console.log(A, B);
});
```

---

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

'evaluated' message printed only once.