# Centralising the Backbone Event Aggregator in RequireJS - how does this work?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, eventaggregator

I am writing a Backbone application using RequireJS for defining modules. I have reached the age old problem of how to pass around the event aggregator without using globals or passing it as a parameter into every single View.

```
vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

I have taken the [approach used here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs#example-with-central-vent) for Marionette, but since I'm not using Marionette (yet), I've adapted it to use the boring old `vent` object:

**vent.js**:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], function (_, Backbone) {
    return _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
});
```

So now in my various modules, I can publish and subscribe, like:

**enquiry-list-view.js**:

```
define(['backbone', 'vent'], function (Backbone, vent) {

    var EnquiryListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            'click .enquiry-list-item-manage': 'manageClick'
        },

        manageClick: function () {
            vent.trigger('navigate', 'enquiry/' + id);
        }
    });
});
```

**app-router.js**:

```
define(['backbone', 'vent'], function (Backbone, vent) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'enquiry/:id': 'enquiryManage'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            //listen out for navigate events
            this.listenTo(vent, 'navigate', this.gotoRoute);
        },

        gotoRoute: function (route) {
            this.navigate(route, { trigger: true });
        }
    });
```

This pattern seems to work okay, the router can listen to the `vent` object and the view can trigger an event on it.

But... how are the router and view both looking at the same object? Doesn't `return _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);` in vent.js always return a new object every time it is required by a different module?

Is there something about RequireJS that I'm not getting, or is `_.extend` doing something to `Backbone.Events`, or is there perhaps something (else) about JavaScript that I don't fully understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AMD, define callback executes only ones. Its result is used in all dependent modules. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218787/while-exporting-new-object-via-require-js-does-it-actually-create-new-object/21219159#21219159) post. I think your question is related to it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing that up. A million decoupling ideas have just flashed before my eyes. RequiresJS is a very good thing :)